# Perform controller action on state change

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a list of events on a state `course.show.events`. I'd like to have a child state i.e. a `course.show.events.event` state which is actually the `course.show.events` state (same controller and view) loaded with performing some controller functions (like `selectEvent(day)`).

The relevant states are:

```
.state 'courses.show.events',
  url: '/events?month'
  controller: 'CourseEventsCtrl as vm'
  templateUrl: 'courses/events/events'
  resolve: { pagination: EventsPaginationResolver }

.state 'courses.show.events.event',
  url: '/:day'
```

I'd like to have access to the `:day` param on `CourseEventsCtrl` and perform some actions depending if it is available, but `$stateParams` only show the params from the `course.show.events` state, not the child `courses.show.events.event` params.

Comment: No idea what last sentence means or what the specific problem is... `the way I'd like to` is as clear as mud

Comment: I've edited the final part, let me know if it's still not clear what I mean.

Comment: post some code... `no access to controller` isn't very clear either. The higher level objective could use a better description also

Comment: I've updated the question with the relevant states, @charlietfl.

Comment: not being access `$stateParams` means there's a problem in your code then. This will go nowhere at this rate. You need to post all relevant code

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're asking, you want to go from `www.example.com/calendar` to `www.example.com/calendar/monday`. You can create a state with `url = '/calender/:day'` and then in your controllers access it from `$routeParams` or `$stateParams` if you're using `ui.router`.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams

Comment: Hey, I've updated the question. I can't access the `$stateParams` relevant to the child state, it seems.

Comment: like @charlietfl said, without the relevant code, we can't help.  What does your child controller look like?